# Problem accessing shared folder on same PC

Tags: windows-7

I have this problem: If I share a folder, users on other PCs can access that folder without problems. However, I cannot acces that folder on my own PC through the network share name.

To clarify: If my PC is called MY_PC, and I share the folder as SharedFolder, the folder can be accessed from other PCs as \\MY_PC\SharedFolder, but if I try this from MY_PC (using Windows Explorer), I get the error message "The specified network name is no longer available."

I am using Windows 7 Professional x64, and I am an Administrator. I have tried with Windows Explorer both as Administrator and normally. This problem also appears on Vista.

Comment: OK, a colleague found the cause of it: The firewall in our Kaspersky anti-virus solution is apparently blocking TCP traffic to one's own PC. So the solution is to add a packet rule that allows this traffic.

Comment: How come that every time somebody begins a sentence with "[Commercial security solution with personal firewall" it ends with something outrageously stupid?